# Draw arrow between two divs, regardless of their position

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to build on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037122/draw-an-arrow-between-two-divs) which explains how to draw an arrow between two divs using svg, but I want to not have to position the arrow manually between the divs. Regardless of where the divs are on the page I want to be able to get the right side point of div1, the left side point of div2, and draw an arrow between them.

For example, if the html file was

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div><p>First div</p></div>
    <div><p>Second div</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the style file was

```css
div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

then I would expect something like this:

[image: inline-block example]

On the other hand, if the html file was

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div><p>First div</p></div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div><p>Second div</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the style file was

```css
div{
    margin-right: 100px;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

then I would expect to see this:

[image: static example]

This is the code that I've worked out so far, based on the comments:

```js
var leftobj = document.getElementById("div1");
var rightobj = document.getElementById("div2");
var leftcoords = leftobj.getBoundingClientRect();
var rightcoords = rightobj.getBoundingClientRect();
var startx = leftcoords.right;
var endx = rightcoords.left;
var starty = (leftcoords.top + leftcoords.bottom) / 2;
var endy = (rightcoords.top + rightcoords.bottom) / 2;
var linepath = `M${startx},${starty} L${endx},${endy}`;
var arr = document.getElementById("arr1");
arr.setAttribute('d', linepath)
```

```html
<div id="div1"><p>First div</p></div>
<div id="div2"><p>Second div</p></div>
<svg width="300" height="100">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path d="M30,150 L100,50" id="arr1"
    style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 1.25px; fill: none;marker-end: url(#arrow);" />
</svg>
```

But this does not draw the arrow where I want it, like I've shown in the pictures. Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: `ReferenceError: rightcoords is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues that need to be addressed at the same time to achieve what you want.

First of all, you need to be working in the same coordinate system, i.e. the origin (0,0) must be the same for the `div`s and the `svg`. To achieve this, it is necessary to set the `margin` and `padding` on all elements to 0 (see the `CSS` code).

Next, you need to overlay the `svg` on top of the `div`s. This can be achieved with `CSS` by using the `position:fixed` property. And then, you need to wrap your `div`s and the `svg` in a container `div`.

If you want to scroll the page as well, then you need to use the `position:absolute` property for the `svg`. In addition, you need to get the amount of page scroll and this can be achieved by adding `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` in the relevant places in the JavaScript code.

I increased the size of the `svg` to cover more of the page.

I added `margin-left: 50px;` to the `div`s so that you will be able to see the arrowhead when you experiment with the `HTML` to test the second layout you present.

Your JavaScript code seems to be working (however, it is worth avoiding `var` today, it is better to use `let` or `const`).

One problem with this approach is that the line joins up the points that you want to join, but the arrowhead goes further. You would need to draw a shorter line if you wanted the arrowhead to stop on the exact point (or find another way to achieve this).

```js
var leftobj = document.getElementById("div1");
var rightobj = document.getElementById("div2");
var leftcoords = leftobj.getBoundingClientRect();
var rightcoords = rightobj.getBoundingClientRect();
var startx = leftcoords.right + window.scrollX;
var endx = rightcoords.left + window.scrollX;
var starty = (leftcoords.top + leftcoords.bottom) / 2 + window.scrollY;
var endy = (rightcoords.top + rightcoords.bottom) / 2 + window.scrollY;
var linepath = `M${startx},${starty} L${endx},${endy}`;
var arr = document.getElementById("arr1");
arr.setAttribute('d', linepath)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.container {
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>First div</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Second div</p>
  </div>
  <svg width="500" height="500">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path d="M30,150 L100,50" id="arr1"
    style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 1.25px; fill: none;marker-end: url(#arrow);" />
</svg>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you!! The last issue I'm running into with your code is that my page is long (vertically) so when I scroll the arrows do not move up and down with the page. Is there any way I can get it to keep its position between div1 and div2 regardless of scrolling?

Comment: I made a few edits to the code and this should enable scrolling in both directions, but it may well depend on how the rest of your page is structured.

Comment: Fantastic, you've solved the problem perfectly. Thanks so much!