# Arrows to connect annotational boxes with content

Tags: reveal.js

Is there a plugin for `reveal.js` to do the following:  I want to have boxes with annotations "overlaid" on my slides (i.e., sitting on top of the main slide text) that have arrows connecting them with slide elements.  I am thinking of something like the following [image: here in this example]

I looked at plenty of reveal.js examples, but was not able to find any presentation that did anything comparable, so I hope it is okay to ask here.

Comment: It looks like <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554167/drawing-arrows-on-an-html-page-to-visualize-semantic-links-between-textual-spans> contains some possible answers to this question.